# AFHTTPClient putpath method

Tags: ios, header, afhttpclient

I have problem with my below funct:

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       sportid, @"sport",
                        country,  SC_PAIS,
                        team,     SC_TEAM,
                        token,    SC_TOKEN,nil];

    [[SCHTTPClientServer sharedClient] setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
       [[SCHTTPClientServer sharedClient] putPath:@"calendarelemfilters/teams" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"RESPonsee %@",responseObject);

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR %@",[error localizedDescription]);

        }];
```

this is my code. I have below error- How can i fix it?

Thanks

"""RESPONSE STRING: <>Apache Tomcat/7.0.26 - Error report

## HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'token' is not present

**type** Status report

**message** Required String parameter 'token' is not present

**description** The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Required String parameter 'token' is not present).

#### Apache Tomcat/7.0.26

2013-09-19 13:10:24.254 ISportsCal[834:907] ERROR Expected status code in (200-299), got 400"""

Comment: What exact format is expected? Have you used Charles to check what is actually sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it with postPath. and also i setted  "setparameter encoding"  as below.

```
[[SCHTTPClientServer sharedClient] setParameterEncoding:AFFormURLParameterEncoding];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's all there in the error message. The server is expecting a parameter called `token` and you aren't passing one in the expected format.

1. What is `SC_TOKEN`? Possibly a capitalization error?
2. Are you sure the server is expecting JSON?
3. Is the server expecting any additional headers?

You may want to download https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger to take a look at your requests. You can download a tool like Postman REST Client, get the put request working there, and then make sure your AFNetworking request matches this.

Comment: 1- sc_token is my parameter.it is good.i checked.
2- Yes the server is expecting json.
3- my headers: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials →
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
Indicates whether or not the response to the request can be exposed when the credentials flag is true. When used as part of a response to a preflight request, this indicates whether or not the actual request can be made using credentials.

true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm
Content-Type →application/json;charset=UTF-8
Server →Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding →chunked

Comment: I don't see where you set the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header. Is your request working in postman? Did you follow my suggestion with the request logger?

Comment: my request is working in postman.  

[self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"*/*"];

im using this header to get all. Am i wrong?

Comment: `Accept` is supposed to specify what content type you want back.  I assume you want to specify JSON there.  You should set your headers identically to how you have them set in Postman.

Comment: actually in my postman header is null ,i mean there is nothing writen.

Comment: /takim?sport=1&team=13&token=testTakim

my url is sth like this. and there is no header.